# How do add this external script into Vuejs

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, computed-properties

I have this script

```
<script id="id" src="link"> </script>
```

How do I convert this using a computed or @click function?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot convert it using `computed` property or `@click` function.

To add and load external scripts, you can use `created` or `mounted` hook for *Vue2* and `setup` function for *Vue3*

Here is the sample code for it:

```
mounted() {
  let externalScript = document.createElement('script')
  externalScript.setAttribute('src', 'YOUR-LINK')
  document.head.appendChild(externalScript)
},
```

You can also add the same logic in a function and

For **Vue2** => call it in the `created` or `mounted` hook.

For **Vue3** => call it in the `setup` function, as the setup function runs before anything else

[Click here for source](https://dev.to/sandrarodgers/add-an-external-script-to-a-vue-component-and-defer-execution-of-logic-on-the-script-4kge#:%7E:text=To%20bring%203rd%20party%20script,do%20logic%20if%20it%20is.)

Comment: You could use the composable that ist provided by Vueuse, which is a really nice helper library for Vue 3: https://vueuse.org/core/useScriptTag/